# Mysite not opening on some PCs and also picture not appearing in search results

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, mysite

I have configured MySite and People Search. Profile pictures are being loaded from UPS.
Problem is, on some PCs in organization user's MySite doesn't open and it shows generic IE error that

> This page can't be displayed   Make sure the web address `http://mysite`
>   is correct

But on other PCs it works. Similarly when I do people search some people see pictures but other people cannot.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. The problem was at the DNS end as it was going to some other IP.